# redirect all errors to an specific page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, frameworks

I have created a laravel project, **in a controller** file I've used **guzzlehttp** to send requests and there's **private web services API's** in that file (controller) .
Now, With every **error in frontend** it will return that API keys including where it's sending the request. 
How can I **hide all of these errors** and debug infos **in frontend** and just show something like "***Oops, Something went wront!***" to website viewers ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hide errors is to edit the `.env` file and change `APP_DEBUG` to `false`:

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```